# Angular 7.2.3, sent post data by "files". (In Express recolect that data by "req.files")

Tags: angular, express, multipartform-data, angular7, angular-httpclient

My Express API REST support upload images.

I used Postman for testing and I receive the image by `req.files`, now in my Angular project, the image is sent by req.body by default.

I tryed set header `'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`, set observe to `files` (getting error because only accept 'body'), set `'Response-Type': 'blob' as 'json'` and more rare things.

My Express Function is:

```js
exports.newPhoto = function(req, res) {
   if(!req.files || !req.files.imageAvatar) { 
            return res.status(300).json({
                status: 'fail', data: 'The request must have imageAvatar file'
            }) 
        }
        imageAvatar = req.files.imageAvatar
        name = imageAvatar.md5 + path.extname(imageAvatar.name)
        ...
}
```

In Angular project:

```js
uploadImage(event) {
    /*upload-avatar.component.ts*/
    this.api.uploadPhoto(event.target.files[0]).subscribe(
    res => {
       ...
    }, err => {
      console.err(err);
    });
  }
```

```js
/*api.service.ts*/
uploadPhoto(file: File) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('imageAvatar', file, file.name);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/usuarios/imagen', formData);
  }
```

I checked a lot of tutorials and other threads of this page and the code is always the same.
Supposedly Angular should treat it as `multipart/form-data` but in the request headers always show `Content-Type: application/json`

Here some image to illustrate the problem:

> My actual problem:
>   [image]
>
> I expeced:
>   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was **set by default** the header in the `interceptor` ‍♂, because a use JWT in my API and for almost all request i must have to put `'Content-type': 'application/json'`

```js
@Injectable()
export class JWTInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const token = this.authenticationService.getToken();
    if (token) {
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: { Authorization: token }
      });
    }

    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

I leave it in case someone happens the same 
I hope you have a good day and happy coding ❤️